# WCF Addressing - Remove the WSA:TO element

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a working set of working WCF web services coded up in **.NET 4.6** - they are making outbound calls to a server. So, they are running in a .EXE (actually will eventually run as a Windows Service).

These web services need to support the WS-Addressing standard:

W3C Web Services Addressing 1.0 - Core  http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-ws-addr-core-20060509

That version of the standard states that the WSA:TO element is optional. What I need is for the WSA:TO element to not to appear in the SOAP output at all. AND I want to do this without having to write a custom SOAP writer as I also need to use WS-SECURITY. I've googled etc etc.

In my binding configuration I have:

```
    <binding name="MyServiceThatMustNotSendWSATO">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10" />
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
```

With an end point of:

```
  <endpoint address="http://destinationserver.com/SomeServiceName/V1"
    behaviorConfiguration="cliBeh" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServiceThatMustNotSendWSATO"
    contract="SomeContract.SomeMethod" name="SomeEndPointName">
    <identity>
      <dns value="somedns" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
```

I've tried all combinations of the textMessageEncoding messageVersion available, but the WSA:TO element is still generated :(

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">tns:ServiceEntryStatusOut_V1</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:88eda3c6-2b6a-4672-8e96-28f0e91c8b4c</a:MessageID>
        <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:1f19a9f3-6e46-47cc-b190-cc7ef71dbc67</a:RelatesTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.com/</a:To>
    </s:Header>
```

So in a nut shell, I need WS-Address fields such as Action, Message ID, RelatesTo, but NOT the To element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever had one of *those* projects? Well, this question as part of a number of nightmare'ish problems I face. But in the end, I overcame them all and got a working solution out the door. It's not a nice solution, but it never was going to be so.

Anyway in a nutshell to solve this particular issue I had to use a custom **ClientMessageInspector** class to remove the offending fields. That class is then part of a custom Behavior Extension. In my question I says that I don't want to do this - in my research this is simply not possible. You do need custom classes to override the default .NET SOAP handling classes.

My custom inspector code ended up as follows:

```
internal class ClientMessageInspector : IEndpointBehavior, IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        //throw new Exception("Exception in ApplyDispatchBehavior : ");
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        //throw new Exception("Exception in ApplyClientBehavior : ");
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(this);
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        //throw new Exception("Exception in BeforeSendRequest : " + request.Headers.MessageId);
        var message = request;
        request = new MyCustomMessage(message);
        return null;
    }

    public class MyCustomMessage : Message
    {
        private readonly Message _message;

        public MyCustomMessage(Message message)
        {
            this._message = message;
        }

        protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
        {
            MethodInfo dynMethod = _message.GetType().GetMethod("OnWriteBodyContents", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            dynMethod.Invoke(_message, new object[] { writer });
        }

        public override MessageHeaders Headers
        {
            get
            {
                // Remove wsa:To header
                var index = this._message.Headers.FindHeader("To", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    this._message.Headers.RemoveAt(index);
                }

                // Remove wsa:ReplyTo header
                index = this._message.Headers.FindHeader("ReplyTo", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    this._message.Headers.RemoveAt(index);
                }

                // Remove VsDebuggerCausalityData (only appears in Dev but here from convenience)
                index = this._message.Headers.FindHeader("VsDebuggerCausalityData", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink");
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    this._message.Headers.RemoveAt(index);
                }

                return this._message.Headers;
            }
        }

        public override MessageProperties Properties
        {
            get { return this._message.Properties; }
        }

        public override MessageVersion Version
        {
            get { return this._message.Version; }
        }

    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        //throw new Exception("Exception in AfterReceiveReply : ");
    }
}
```

The binding required is complicated but ends up as follows. The key thing is to use the custom Behavior Extension to do the heavy lifting to remove those fields.

```
  <system.serviceModel>

    <extensions>

      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="myBehaviorExtensionElement"
             type="MySecurityBE.MyBehaviorExtensionElement, MySecurityBE, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>

    </extensions>

    <bindings>

      <customBinding>

        <binding name="ServiceName_soap12" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
        sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
        maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10" />
          <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
        </binding>

      </customBinding>

    </bindings>

    <behaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="cliBeh">
          <myBehaviorExtensionElement/>
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="BradTestClientKey"/>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <defaultCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="localhost2"/>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

    <client>

      <endpoint address="http://localhost.fiddler/TestRigClient_WS/Services/MyService"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceName_soap12"
                contract="GenericFileTransferService.GenericFileTransfer"
                name="ServiceName_soap12" behaviorConfiguration="cliBeh">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost2"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>


    </client>

    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" maxMessagesToLog="30000000" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000000"/>
    </diagnostics>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

I wish anyone facing the same battle good luck. Long live REST and may SOAP die a nice quiet death it so richly deserves (just my opinion after the nightmare year I spent on that project).

Comment: I've not really worked with SOAP before, but my recent experience has been very similar. Your code along with a couple of other tips here and there has *nearly* got my single query of a single dataset via SOAP working!